# PHPUnit incompatible version with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to run unit tests using PHPUnit in a CI/CD setup. The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
PHPUnit testing framework version 6 or greater is required when running on PHP 7.0 or greater. Run the command 'composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade' in order to fix this.
```

But I have the correct version of PHPUnit with PHP 7.2.14. I tried running the suggested command but nothing works.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Hope someone with experience has an idea.

Regards.

Comment: is that the only version of phpunit on the path? Search the drive for any other versions?  run the command `phpunit --version`  from the command line. i.e. no prefix.

Comment: From the pipeline or the command line I'm still getting the same error. No other phpunit installed.

Comment: @Macaret Did you try to run some test without Drupal? For example, you can create a simple test project, that will contain one class and one unit-test and you can try to run this test in your envelopment

Comment: I'm able to run the test successfully on my local project. Something on the server doesn't work. I've tried removing phpunit, adding different versions, upgrading, etc.

Comment: @Macaret What version of PHPUnit and PHP do you have in the local environment?

Comment: 7.1.19 PHP and 6.5.3 PHPUnit. I've tried with multiple version, on local it works but on the server it doesn't.

Comment: @Macaret  you can create a simple test project (without Drupal), that will contain one unit-test and you can try to run this test in the server. It might show some problems.

Comment: I ran a simple phpunit test and it worked. phpunit 6.5.5 was installed. This is the project https://github.com/drmonkeyninja/phpunit-simple-example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187189/discussion-between-maxim-fedorov-and-macaret).

Comment: Shot in the dark: https://www.drupal.org/node/2957906 - see the part at the end about changes to the phpunit.xml configuration file

Comment: I don't have a local configuration based on phpunit.xml.dist.

Comment: Strange.. The message `drupal-phpunit-upgrade` is indicating a Drupal installation but the project (shared in comments) is not based on Drupal. Maybe there is a typo in your CI script? Runned from the correct location? Echo a `pwd` command in CI script before the phpunit command to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was... It seems that there was a previous installation of PHPUnit, with a version of 4.5, somewhere on the server outside my Drupal project. I manually updated that version to and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably version of PHP for `cli` and `cgi` could be different. As you are running `phpunit` from console, try also run `php -v` to find out which version is used for console.

Also, you error message suggest you:

```
Run the command 'composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade' in order to fix this.
```

Probably that will fix your issue

Comment: PHP 7.2.4 and I did try to run the command without any luck. I'm still getting the same issue.